# stuck on a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a query that works just fine in the latest mysql.

```
select Title, Link
from PlaylistItem
where PlaylistId = 1;
```

which returns:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Title                     | Link                                        |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
| Regina Spektor - Fidelity | https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wigqKfLWjvM |
+---------------------------+---------------------------------------------+
```

But when I write a stored procedure, I get an empty result set.

The stored procedure looks like this:

```
/* Fetch all playlist items for a playlist */
delimiter //
create procedure MixtapeDating.GetPlaylist
(
    in Id int
)
begin
    select Id, Title, Link
    from PlaylistItem
    where PlaylistId = @Id; 
end //
delimiter ;
```

I run the procedure like thus:

```
call GetPlaylist(1);
```

Comment: how do you run the procedure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mysql variables prefixed by `@` are [session variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), not stored procedure level variables, so `@id` is not the same as `id`. Moreover, `id` is also a fieldname, so you must rename your parameter.

```
delimiter //
create procedure MixtapeDating.GetPlaylist
(
    in var_Id int
)
begin
    select Id, Title, Link
    from PlaylistItem
    where PlaylistId = var_Id; 
end //
delimiter ;
```